# Is tensorflow running on GPU or CPU? (windows)

Tags: tensorflow

Im trying since a while to install tensorflow-gpu and had a lot of trouble with CUDA. First the Visual Studio integration in the CUDA setup always gave me an error, but if i leave out the Visual studio integration during CUDA installation, the installation is working.
Is the Studio integration mandatory for using tensorflow-gpu?

So then i installed all of the 3 patches for CUDA 9.0 and placed the Cudnn files in the folder.
Next, i went to my environtment variables and added this path (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0)

So when i open a command prompt and import tensorflow, in all tutorials i saw about this topic there where some lines about stuff being loaded successfully? I dont have these.

So im running this little code

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

And am getting this as answer

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" C:/Users/Felix/Documents/Uni/Semesterarbeit/doesitwork.py
2018-06-21 13:41:41.187933: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-06-21 13:41:41.748188: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085
pciBusID: 0000:21:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.63GiB
2018-06-21 13:41:41.748527: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-06-21 13:43:44.853239: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-06-21 13:43:44.853436: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
2018-06-21 13:43:44.853564: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
2018-06-21 13:43:44.853860: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:21:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Device mapping:
2018-06-21 13:43:45.164653: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:284] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:21:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:21:00.0, compute capability: 6.1


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is this what its supposed to look like? 
Looking forward to an answer
Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the last line in your log.

'job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:21:00.0, compute capability: 6.1'